# URISyntaxException in gradle environment variable while testing

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a build.gradle as follows

```
task setDockerHost {
  group 'Docker'
  description 'Gets the docker host ip from your OS'
  def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  exec {
    commandLine './src/main/resources/scripts/get-docker-host.sh', '60'
    standardOutput = stdout
  }
  project.ext.set('DOCKERHOST', "$stdout")
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
  doFirst { println "DockerHost is $project.DOCKERHOST" }
  environment 'DOCKERHOST', "$project.DOCKERHOST"
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
  testLogging {
    events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'standardOut'
  }
  reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
}
```

I define a DOCKERHOST env variable as above and want to use in my groovy test class:

```
class MyClass extends Specification {
  RESTClient client = new RESTClient("http://"+System.getenv('DOCKERHOST')+":9090/")
...
}
```

In the execution my println works: DockerHost is 192.168.99.100

But when I run the this test it throws:

[image: URIerror]

**I already tried replacing \n, \r and spaces by "". I also try removing the protocol from the URL (aka 192.168.99.10:9090) and it tells me that the same error occurs at index 0**

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm guessing there's a space at the end before the `:9090`... I assume it works if you hardcoded it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure it out in which char was the problem but I was able to solve it but replacing strings like crazy:

```
String url = ("http://" + System.getenv('DOCKERHOST') + ":9090/").replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").replace(" ", "")


RESTClient client = new RESTClient(url)
```

I've spent like a day trying to figure this out... hopefully for someone else will be quicker.